# Animation of Auto Layout Constraint Not Happening inside NSTableCellView

Tags: swift, nstableview, nstablecellview, nsanimationcontext

I'm trying to get an auto layout constraint to update with animation inside an `NSTableCellView`. The constraint is updating fine, but it's not happening with animation.

The following code is executed inside `tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)`:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
  context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
  context.duration = 0.3
  cell.progressWidthConstraint.constant = CGFloat(progress)
  cell.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
})
```

The `cell` is my `NSTableCellView`, and `progressWidthConstraint` is the width constraint on an `NSView` inside the cell.

Is there something special I need to do to get animation to work in a `NSTableCellView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) in
  context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
  cell.progressWidthConstraint.animator().constant = CGFloat(progress)
  context.duration = 0.3
  cell.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: Same result. No animation. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That worked! So I need the `animator()` proxy, 'eh. Interesting. Thank you very much!